Copy/clone imported JPG from one sheet to another and I don't have access to the original JPG
Using this as a guide: Excel Vba Copy Picture to new sheet
I have this code which is equivalent only I'm on a MAC. I can't get anything to paste on the destination sheet. I've been the last 3 hours on this and it just fails every time. I also tried AddPicture but they always require the source file and I don't have that. I'm copying an imported JPG from another sheet to my current sheet.
Debugger is no help as I get to the copy statement and the debugger tells me "Object Variable not set" when I hover over origPic.Type in the loop.
Sub CopyImageFromAcDiagram()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim origPic As Shape
    
    sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arc Diagram")
    destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Executive Review")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each origPic In sourceSheet.Shapes
       If origPic.Type = msoPicture And origPic.Name = "ArchPicture" Then
         origPic.Copy
         With destinationSheet
            .Select
            .Range("E1").Select
            .Paste
        End With
        Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
      End If
   Next origPic
    
    'ThisWorkbook.Protect_This_Sheet
End Sub


You should avoid using .select:
   Sub CopyImageFromAcDiagram()
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
        Dim origPic As Shape
    
        Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arc Diagram")
        Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Executive Review")
        
        For Each origPic In sourceSheet.Shapes
            If origPic.Type = msoPicture And origPic.Name = "ArchPicture" Then
                origPic.Copy
                destinationSheet.Paste destinationSheet.Range("E1") ' Paste the image to destination sheet
                destinationSheet.Shapes(destinationSheet.Shapes.Count).Placement = xlMoveAndSize ' Adjust the placement of the pasted image
            End If
        Next origPic
    End Sub

